# Python - Matplotlib - Plotting incomplete data on chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to write program to generate burndown chart. The x-axis is of dates. The y-axis shows remaining hours on a particular date. The problem is that data is not present for all the dates in advance as it is a burndown chart. So this results in error -

```
"ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension"
```

So my question is what default values I can assign to the remaining points on Y-axis?
I will paste actual code if this information is not sufficient. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want, but by using masked arrays you can avoid plotting specific points. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540294/how-to-handle-an-asymptote-discontinuity-with-matplotlib). Or maybe you'd like something more like [this](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/howto_faq.html#skip-dates-where-there-is-no-data), which skips them on the x-axis as well as not plotting them?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is 2 1/2 years old, but I had a similar problem with plotting graphs with missing data and thought that masked arrays were more complex than they needed to be.

My solution was to put the `numpy.inf` value at any points where I was missing data and then use the `'o-'` option when calling `matplotlib.pyplot.plot`.  This will make lines be broken where you don't have data, but if you have a single data point somewhere missing data on each side of it, you get a circle.

The only downside is that you end up with circles at every point on the line, so it might not be pretty.