# How to plot f(x) as x goes to infinity

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting a curve from some data points:

```
points = [[0.0, 0.0], [1, 3], [3, 5]]
```

... and I want it to reach, say, y = 10 as x goes to **infinity**. In other words, the extra "point" to append would be: `[float('inf'), 10]`

Is there a way to tell `matplotlib` to plot the **asymptotic** behaviour of this last part of the curve?

Matplotlib disregards `float('info')`, so I guess there should be another way to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to handle an asymptote/discontinuity with Matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540294/how-to-handle-an-asymptote-discontinuity-with-matplotlib)

Comment: yes, I read it, but I didn't get any of the three answers there. How can I apply them to my problem?

Comment: `matplotlib` won't plot infinite values (`np.inf` or `float('inf')`, because that doesn't make sense! You could try using a large but non-infinite number, e.g. `sys.maxsize`.

Comment: Analytically speaking of course it makes sense... maybe numerically it's not feasible. Ok.

Comment: It don’t get the argument why it soesn’t make sense. It it wouldn’t make sense, `np.inf` wouldn’t be a valid floating point value

Answer (score 6):

You can't plot a function of infinity because it isn't a number.  I think the only way to achieve the effect that you want is with a broken axis and the data point plotted at some arbitrarily large number.  An example of how to do the broken plot [is available from the official matplotlib site.](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html)

The basic idea is to create two subplots with borders cleverly removed so as to look like a single plot then add some fancy diagonal lines to make it look like a conventional "broken" plot.  You can plot your infinity data point in its own subplot by substituting a sufficiently large number (to make the curve look right). Then just relabel the tick to infinity (`ax.set_xticks([large_number])` `ax.set_xticklabels(['\infty']`) assuming `ax` is the second plot that only has your infinity point) and you're in business!

I have recently used a modified form of the above example to plot a point "at infinity".  I have code that does this but it's full of references to my specific data so it will probably be about as helpful to you as the official example.