# Python-Matplotlib Plotting with infiniite f(x) values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to graph the tan function in matplotlib.
The `tan` function goes to infinity when the value inserted is `pi/2`. The problem is that I dont know how to deal with infinite numbers in Matplotlib or in turn, infinitly small ranges  to be able to plot it. One of the problems is the line that goes down, to try to connect the last dot drawn up top, with the first after `pi/2`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

x_values = numpy.linspace(-5,5,num=1000)
y_values = numpy.tan(x_values)
plt.plot(x_values, y_values)
plt.show()
```

This is the output:

[image: Image created by Matplotlib]

This is because this function gets 1000 points to plot, not infinite points, but it doesn't create the image that I want, I want an image like the one that a graphic calculator would produce.
What can I do?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21204887/5785250

Comment: I found a similar question, now nobody needs to answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204740/drawing-tangent-plot-in-python-matplotlib/21204887#21204887

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to plot a discontinuous function

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi, nan
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start, stop, num, eps = -5, 5, 200, 0.003
data = np.linspace(start, stop, num)

shift = (data + pi/2) % pi
data = data[(eps < shift) & (shift < pi - eps)]
asymptotes = np.r_[start:stop:pi] - (start + pi/2) % pi + pi

xx = np.r_[data, asymptotes]
yy = np.r_[np.tan(data), [nan]*len(asymptotes)]
order = xx.argsort()   

xlim = [start, stop]
ylim = [-25, 25]

plt.figure(figsize=(8,12))
plt.xlim(xlim)
plt.ylim(ylim)

plt.plot([asymptotes]*2, 
         [[i]*len(asymptotes) for i in ylim], 
         'k--', linewidth=1)

plt.plot(xx[order], yy[order])
plt.show()
```

- `asymptotes` - discontinuity points of the tangent function
- `eps` - a radius of the excluded neighborhood around the discontinuity points
- `shift` - distance from data to nearest breakpoints on the left

[image]

Comment: How do you draw the vertical black lines with points in them, in the asymptotes?

Comment: @Flavio `plt.plot([asymptotes]*2, [[i]*len(asymptotes) for i in ylim], color='black', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)`