# clean up plot of tan(x)

Tags: plot, sympy

I want to visualize the roots of  `tan(xi) = tanh(xi), xi>0` and my plot

```
plot(tan(pi*xi), tanh(pi*xi), (xi, 0, 4), ylim=(-1, 2))
```

comes out like this

[image: sympy plot]

where one sees the actual roots, `xi_i \approx pi*(n+1/4), n=1, ...` but also
fake roots at `pi*(n+1/2)`, the reason why being `sympy` plotting algorithm that draws a vertical line between plus and minus infinity.

I tried to avoid the adaptive sampling and using a low sampling rate to no avail.  Other programs, eg `gnuplot`, give me a more reasonable plot, at least in view of my concerns, that is...

[image: gnuplot]

Eventually my question is, is it possible to avoid those vertical lines in `sympy`'s `plot()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sympy uses matplotlib as a backend for plotting; the root cause is that matplotlib connects the dots even around a singularity. If one plots with numpy, the direct access to y-values being plotted allows one to [replace overly large numbers with nan or infinity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2542065). If staying within sympy, such tight control over numerics does not appear to be available.  The best I could do is to split the range into a list of smaller ranges that do not include singularities, using the knowledge of the specific function tan(pi*x):

```
import math
from sympy import *
xi = symbols('xi')
xmin = 0
xmax = 4
ranges = [(xi, n-0.499, n+0.499) for n in range(math.ceil(xmin+0.5), math.floor(xmax+0.5))]
ranges.insert(0, (xi, 0, 0.499))
ranges.append((xi, math.floor(xmax+0.5) - 0.499, xmax))
plot((tanh(pi*xi), (xi, xmin, xmax)), *[(tan(pi*xi), ran) for ran in ranges], ylim=(-1, 2))
```

Output:

[image: tangent plot]

Answer (score 0):

When a curve has singularities, it can plotted by segments, excluding the singularities. A tiny interval around the each singularity is built  with `math.nextafter(a,b)` which returns `a` plus the smallest possible increment for a float, in direction of `b`.

```python
from sympy import init_printing, symbols, plot
from sympy import singularities, Interval, tan, pi
from math import nextafter

init_printing()
x = symbols('x')

# The function to plot
y = tan(pi*x)

# Split x range at x singularities
min_x = next_x = 0
max_x = 4 # 4*pi
segments = []
undefs = singularities(y, x, domain=Interval(min_x, max_x))
for u in undefs:
    # Add a subrange up to singularity for singularities within x range
    if (u >= min_x) and (u <= max_x):
        segments.append((x, next_x, nextafter(u, u-1)))
        next_x = nextafter(u, u+1)
# Add last segment
if u <= max_x: segments.append((x, next_x, max_x))

# Plot all segments
plots = plot(*[(y, segment) for segment in segments], ylim=(-2,2), show=False)
plots.aspect_ratio = (1,1)
plots.show()
```

[image]

Of course you can use the same color for each curve segment.

Comment: Is your answer different from the accepted one?

Comment: @gboffi: This is an improvement, the singularities are computed using sympy rather than hard-coded values. This solution works with any function, just change `y` expression.