# How to plot tan(x).*x in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, sympy

In MATLAB I can do `ezplot("x.*tan(x)")` to plot the following:

[image: ezplot tan(x)*x]

While in Symbolab it will be like this

[image: Symbolab result]

While in Python I use Numpy or Sympy, but still, the graph is so different

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.functions.elementary.trigonometric import tan
from sympy.plotting.plot import plot

x = symbols('x')
eqn = tan(x)*x
plot(eqn, (x, 0, 10), ylim=(-20, 20))
```

[image: Sympy plot]

How can I get an image with Python equivalent to that in MATLAB and Symbolab?

Comment: The image is the same, apart from it running from 0 to 10, rather than -10 to 10 and it plotting asymptotes. I presume your question is thus how to not plot the asymptotes using sympy?

Comment: Seems like the only way with sympy is to plot the continuous slices separately: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36681255/13138364

Comment: Also see sympy#18455: [Improve singularity handling for plots](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/18455)

Comment: And sympy#17738: [Plot of discontinuous piecewise should not connect edges](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/17738)

Comment: If you'd use matplotlib with numpy, you could use masking, as in [how to handle an asymptote/discontinuity with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540294/how-to-handle-an-asymptote-discontinuity-with-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

You can try fplot for a continuous uncertainty. Then limit the plot for x and y axis.

```
fplot(@(x)x.*tan(x))
xlim([-10,10])
ylim([-5 10])
grid on
```

[Matlab plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O23zU.jpg)
The dashed line in plot are the same as the vertical lines in sympy plots.

In python you may use pyplot with markers instead of sympy plot to avoid continuity vertical lines.

```
from string import whitespace
from sympy import symbols
from sympy import *
from sympy.functions.elementary.trigonometric import tan
from sympy.plotting.plot import plot
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = symbols('x')
eqn = tan(x)*x

xx = np.linspace(-100, 100, 10000)
yy = lambdify(x, eqn)(xx)
plt.plot(xx,yy,'.')
plt.ylim(-5, 10)
plt.xlim(-20, 20)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Outcome [Pyplot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNIN8.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The question is how to do this in Python. Your answer is MATLAB code, but they already know how to do it in MATLAB (and even included their MATLAB code+output in the question).

Comment: Huh. My mistake.